# Geonames java client: How to retrieve the country and adminName1?

Tags: java, geonames

Geonames database works fine for me when to query via WEB. However, there are java packages `org.geonames` with classes `WebService`, `Toponym` and other ones, which seem to do the same from within java application. So, I try to use `org.geonames` for creating a query like

```
https://secure.geonames.org/countrySubdivision?lat=47.03&lng=30.2&username=myUserName
```

which, when sending via WEB, returns xml nwith `countryName` and `adminName1` tags. However, I cannot find appropriate method (methods) in `org.geonames` returning object with `countryName` and `adminName1` by given latitude and longitude.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are in the class `Toponym`, not in the package.
[Here](https://www.geonames.org/source-code/javadoc/org/geonames/Toponym.html) is the javadoc with all the methods.

And here is an example from their [website](https://www.geonames.org/source-code/).

```java
WebService.setUserName("demo"); // add your username here
 
ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
searchCriteria.setQ("zurich");
ToponymSearchResult searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) {
   System.out.println(toponym.getName()+" "+ toponym.getCountryName());
}
```

Comment: thanks for a quick and helpful reply. I start to think about something like 'findNearBy'. By the way, does  'searchCriteria' provide searching for latitude and longitude?

Comment: @Spectorsky sorry but I know nothing about `Geonames`. I just googled `geonames java` and your answer was in the first link. I suggest you to look at the javadoc by yourself

Comment: @Arnaud_Claudel, thanks. Of course, I've googled too, but I sought for 'countrySubdivision'. Apparantly, there is no 1-1 mapping between web and java interfaces. Thanks again.